# How to search with "or" clauses in Sphinx?

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I have the following index with sphinx :

```
source src1
{
    type                    = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = ...
    sql_pass        = ...
    sql_db          = ....
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    sql_sock                =  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT anuncio_id,data_criacao,titulo,descricao,categoria1_titulo,categoria1_id,categoria2_titulo,categoria2_id,categoria3_titulo,categoria3_id,categoria4_titulo,categoria4_id FROM ccsprool_indice

    sql_field_string = titulo
    sql_field_string = descricao
    sql_field_string = categoria1_titulo
    sql_field_string = categoria2_titulo
    sql_field_string = categoria3_titulo
    sql_field_string = categoria4_titulo
    sql_attr_uint = categoria1_id
    sql_attr_uint = categoria2_id
    sql_attr_uint = categoria3_id
    sql_attr_uint = categoria4_id
    sql_attr_timestamp = data_criacao        
    sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM ccsprool_indice WHERE anuncio_id=$id

}

index produtos_sprool
{
    source          = src1
    path            = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/produtos_sprool
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = none
    charset_type        = utf-8
    html_strip       = 1 
    min_word_len            = 3
    min_prefix_len          = 0
    min_infix_len           = 3
    wordforms = /usr/local/sphinx/data/wordforms.txt
}
```

I need to check if an item is in categoria1_id, or categoria2_id, categoria3_id, or categoria4_id

can I do that with Sphinx ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the task correctly this should help:

$cl->SetSelect('*, categoria1_id=N or categoria2_id=N or categoria3_id=N or categoria4_id=N as fil');
$cl->SetFilter('fil', array(1));

This will return all documents that have one of categoria1_id/categoria2_id/categoria3_id/categoria4_id set to N.